# Implementing CSS on netbiscuits JSP

Tags: javascript, jsp, jakarta-ee, struts, netbiscuits

I just want to implement CSS on my JSP which has the net-biscuits code in it. I am directly starting my JSP code from the `<FORM>` tag. I worte:

```
 Some code -----
<span class="cart_bubble"><bean:write name="keywordform" property="cartvalue"/></span>
 Some code -----
```

but I cant see the CSS on this page though I am getting the value from the bean.

The CSS is:

```
.cart_bubble{
position: absolute;
right: 0px;
top: 0px;
padding: 5px;
width: auto;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(10% 64% 90deg,#AE1321, #FC7C4A);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 37%, from(#FC7C4A), to(#AE1321));
color: white;
line-height: 4px;
font-size: 11px;
font-weight: bold;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
cursor: pointer;
border: 0px solid white;
-moz-box-shadow: 1px 2px 2px #9a9b9b;
-webkit-box-shadow: 1px 2px 2px #9a9b9b;
margin: -3px 0px 0px -3px;
}
```

Please suggest a solution to my problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I do not understand how the code you provided relates to your problem. Somewhere in the JSP you must include the CSS...

Comment: I have include the css on my JSP still the issue exists

Answer (score 0):

First you need to include the CSS file using the external tag like this:

[external file="your.css"/]

and then reference the style in your FORM biscuit:

[FORM class="cart_bubble"]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. But I have already tried including my own css on the netbiscuits page still I am unable to solve the problem